# Could not get XPATH of Elements in Tree List of a Page

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In my application in order to find(Child element) an organisation I need to expand the Tree View of Org(Parent element).But I could not get exact XPATH of any element which is present in the Tree View.

Please see the following XML which is present in my HTML page.

```
<?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX=TVNS />
 <?IMPORT NAMESPACE=TVNS  IMPLEMENTATION="/webctrl_client/1_0/treeview.htc" />
 <tvns:treeview id="TreeView1" defaultStyle="font-size:8pt;font-family:Tahoma;" selectedNodeIndex="0" HelperID="__TreeView1_State__" systemImagesPath="/webctrl_client/1_0/treeimages/" showLines="false" indent="19" onexpand="javascript: if (this.clickedNodeIndex != null) this.queueEvent(&#39;onexpand&#39;, this.clickedNodeIndex)" oncollapse="javascript: if (this.clickedNodeIndex != null) this.queueEvent(&#39;oncollapse&#39;, this.clickedNodeIndex)" oncheck="javascript: if (this.clickedNodeIndex != null) this.queueEvent(&#39;oncheck&#39;, this.clickedNodeIndex)" onselectedindexchange="javascript: if (event.oldTreeNodeIndex != event.newTreeNodeIndex) this.queueEvent(&#39;onselectedindexchange&#39;, event.oldTreeNodeIndex + &#39;,&#39; + event.newTreeNodeIndex)">
    <tvns:treenode Expanded="False" ImageUrl="images/folder_purple.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="images/folderopen_purple.gif" Target="RightFrame">Sale History
       <tvns:treenode NavigateUrl="BOFrame.aspx?Parameters=&amp;show=BusinessObjectSearcher.aspx?Parameters=0_ABC.nRde.ISaleHistory_true_abcTree.aspx" ImageUrl="images/find.gif" Target="RightFrame">
    Find Sale History
       </tvns:treenode>
    </tvns:treenode>
  </tvns:treeview>
```

I could not expand the TreeView.
Please let me know how to automate such test cases.

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you, please tell how you are attempting to get the XPath. It sounds like you're using a DOM inspector tool in a browser? And what element are you trying to get the XPath of? What do you mean by "element which is present in the Tree View" -- are you saying it's a descendant of the treeview element? Please show the HTML for the element you're trying to get the XPath of, with context showing its relationship to the `<treeview>` element.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question as @LarsH said.

Comment: @LarsH  Please find update code snippet if it could help you to figure out anything. Sry I could not provide you snapshot as reputation is low.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I can suggest you to try the below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//treeview[@id='TreeView1']"))
```

Cheers!

Comment: The OP says he is getting the XPath of the Tree View but he wants the XPath of some other element.

Comment: Can you suggest what would be the Xpath for accessing child elements. I'm unable to get by driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='TreeView1']/tvns:treenode[0]"))

Answer (score 0):

Please Try using following snippet

driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='TreeView1']/tvns:treenode[1]").click();